# Incrementing array in for loop returning NaN [MATLAB]

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, increment, nan

I want to create a nested for loop that pulls 1x2 double elements from a 1x4 cell array `V` and adds them together. 1x2 double elements contain numbers (ex. `[0.234 0.325]`). I want to add those four 1x2 double elements together and store the value in an incrementing counter `VSum`. However, MATLAB is returning `[NaN NaN]`. How do I fix this?

Additional info: A is a 50x50 cell array

```
VSum = [0 0];

for i = 1:1:size(G,2)
    for j = 1:1:size(G,1)
        for p = 1:1:4
            V{p} = (A{i,j}{p}*Q)/(2*pi*norm(Z{i,j}{p}));
            VSum = V{p}+VSum;
        end 
    end
end
```

Comment: what is `Z`? I'm guessing there is a `0` somewhere in `Z`

Comment: or at least `norm(Z{i,j}{p})` is `0` somewhere

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus Apologies, I should have mentioned that. Z is a 50x50 cell array just like A. Z contains many 1x4 cells. I am not sure if a 0 is present in any of those cells.

Answer (score 0):

If just a single value in the three-dimensional cell-array `Z` is `0`, then this will return `[NaN NaN]`. [Here's more details on where NaN vs Inf come from](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/infinity-and-nan.html). Just a `0` in the denominator will create `Inf` (or `-Inf`) but adding `Inf + -Inf` would probably create a `NaN`

Comment: You're right. I think I know what I did wrong now, but I'll have to write more code to confirm. I'll give an update later. Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: With your answer, I was able to determine that there was indeed a 0 and NaN in array A. By writing an if-else statement to exclude the affected cell, the loop ran with no problem and returned numbers for VSum. Thanks again.